2 LINQ queries use the same joins. Is there a way to "factor out" the joins and gain a performance benefit?
Here are two example queries:
var queryA =
    from t1 in context.T1
    join t2 in context.T2
    where
        tl.colA == desiredColAValue
    select new ObjectA(valuesFromQueryA)
;

var queryB =
    from t1 in context.T1
    join t2 in context.T2
    where
        tl.colA != null
        && t2.id == someId
    select new ObjectB(quiteOtherValuesNowFromQueryB)
;

Note that their joins are exactly the same, but the where conditions and objects returned are different.
In my application there are more joins and the queries are executed in the same procedure. Is there a way to "factor out" the joins in an elegant and profitable way (so that the joins are only executed once)?
I've searched online and it seems that CTE's are not supported in LINQ.

I think you need to understand how deferred execution works with regards to LINQ queries like this. For example, neither queryA or queryB will actually execute anything here until you start iterating over the results.

CTEs are not supported in Entity Framework - is that what you meant? But they may well be supported by other ORMs. So what exactly are you using?

I'm no expert on database execution plans. But I would expect the queries to start filtering one table, and then looking up rows in the other. Ideally in the order that eliminates as many rows as possible as early as possible. Since the filters are completely different I don't see how any work could be reused between the queries.

Common table expressions are not related to LINQ. It's not clear how they could play a role here.

Usually you should create intermediate query and reuse in other queries:

var commonQuery =
    from t1 in context.T1
    join t2 in context.T2 on ... equals ...
    select new { t1, t2 }
;

var queryA =
    from c in commonQuery
    where
        c.t1.colA == desiredColAValue
    select new ObjectA(valuesFromQueryA)
;
    
var queryB =
    from c in commonQuery
    where
        c.t1.colA != null
        && c.t2.id == someId
    select new ObjectB(quiteOtherValuesNowFromQueryB)
;    

